# <apex:inputFile> 'accept' and 'contentType' on VF page only working when not called from mobile

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, contenttype

```
<apex:inputFile value="{!attachment.body}" fileName="{!attachment.name}" id="file" contentType="{!attachment.ContentType}" accept="image/*,application/pdf"/>
```

If I call this from my desktop browser, I'm only able to chose files that match the criteria of *accept* and the *ContentType* is for example set to *image/jpeg*. That's fine.

Called from my Nexus 5 via Salesforce1, I can select any other file type and the contentType is not correctly set. The ContentType is always set to *application/octet-stream*.

EDIT Controller Method:

```
public PageReference doAddAttachment() { 
    PageReference result;
    attachment.OwnerId = UserInfo.getUserId();
    attachment.ParentId = expense.Id;
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;
    if(attachment.body != null) {
        try {
            insert attachment;
            result = new PageReference('/apex/expenseViewMobile?id=' + expense.Id);
            result.setRedirect(true);
        } 
        catch (DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'File upload failed.'));
        } 
        finally {
            attachment.body = null;
            attachment = new Attachment(); 
        }
    }
    else {
        ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'You need to select a file.'));
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: do you have controller code written ?

Comment: sure, I added the controller method in my post

Answer (score -1):

Why not just use javascript and the ajax toolkit instead with a regular html5 input file that also has accept

note this will also allow you upload file up to 25mbs instead of 10mb with apex:inputfile

```
 <apex:form id="form_Upload">
 <apex:pageBlock >

  <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">

    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem >

      <input type="file" id="myuploadbutton" accept="image/*,application/pdf"/>

    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>

  </apex:pageBlockSection>
       <apex:pageBlockButtons location="bottom"> 


      <input type="button" id="uploadBtn" value="Attach File"/>
      <apex:commandButton action="{!back}" value="Cancel" /> 
      </apex:pageBlockButtons>
 </apex:pageBlock>


 </apex:form>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/soap/ajax/33.0/apex.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

  <script>
  j$ = jQuery.noConflict();


  if(!window.FileReader){
  top.location.href='Set this to you current page';

  }

  var thefiletoupload;
  var realfilesize;
  var realfilename;

  function handleFileUpload(files,obj)
{
  if(files[0].name === undefined){
  alert("You did not selected a file or your browser doesn't support this functionality");
  return;
  }
    if(files[0].name.length > 80){
   alert("Your file name must be less than 80 Letters");
  return;
  }

sforce.connection.sessionId = '{!GETSESSIONID()}'; 
   for (var i = 0; i< files.length; i++) 
   {       
       f = files[i];  
       var reader = new FileReader();                    
                reader.file = f;                               
                reader.onerror = function(e) 
                {
                    switch(e.target.error.code) 
                    {
                        case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                          alert('File Not Found!');  
                           break;
                        case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
                        alert('File is not readable');
                            break;
                        case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
                            break; // noop
                        default:
                            alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
                    };
                };     

                reader.onabort = function(e) 
                {                  
                     alert('File read cancelled');                   
                };

                reader.onload = function(e) 
                {

                            var att = new sforce.SObject("Attachment");
                            att.Name = this.file.name;
                            att.ContentType = this.file.type;
                            att.ParentId = 'Get id from page param or i use hiddden input tab with an id like j$('#sfid').val() and html {!yourobj.ID}';
        att.Body = (new sforce.Base64Binary(e.target.result)).toString();

        sforce.connection.create([att],
        {
            onSuccess : function(result, source) 
            {
                if (result[0].getBoolean("success")) 
                {
                        top.location.href='your page/ plus id';         
                } 
                else 
                {
                    console.log("failed to create attachment " + result[0]);
                }
            }, 
            onFailure : function(error, source) 
            {
                console.log("An error has occurred " + error);
            }
        });                             
                };               
                reader.readAsBinaryString(f);
   }
}
  j$(document).ready(function()
{
j$('#myuploadbutton').bind('change', function () {
   realfilesize = this.files[0].size;
   realfilename = this.files[0].name;
   thefiletoupload = this.files;
});
j$('#uploadBtn').on('click',function(){
console.log('clicked');
if (thefiletoupload !== undefined && thefiletoupload !== null){
document.getElementById("uploadBtn").disabled = true;
handleFileUpload(thefiletoupload ,obj);
}
else{
alert('You have not Uploaded a file');
}

});

});
  </script>
</apex:page>
```